# Write/read data consistency with mysql replication and PHP7

Tags: php, mysql, replication

How to deal with read/write data consistency in multiple mysql (or mariadb) slaves that may potentially lag after the master? I'm especially interested in situation when write and read requests are asynchronous, like one ajax requests updates the data, and another is supposed to read the new values.

One approach I've seen is to use MASTER_POS_WAIT (or MASTER_GTID_WAIT), but that will require every time an additional call to the master before reading from the slave.

In past the mysqlnd_ms php5 extension can be set for strong data consistency levels. But it is no longer available for php7 (there is a port for php7, but it is unofficial and does not work with mariadb).

How do you deal with data consistency in PHP7 nowadays?